# Removing drag effect from angular material date picker

Tags: angular, angular-material

In this minimalistic example of a date range picker using Angular material 15, how can I disable the drag effect in the calendar.

I want to prevent the user from click+drag the selected date to another another date option.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>



import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Basic date range picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'date-range-picker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'date-range-picker-overview-example.html',
})
export class DateRangePickerOverviewExample {}
```

Comment: Angular Material provides a DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy which can give a possibility to enhance the createDrag method. Here is an example of custom selection strategy https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#date-range-picker-selection-strategy